# Block after block Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this structure, when elements are inline:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">Block 1</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">Block 2</div> 
</div>
```

How to place these elements in block with margin between for dimension < 350px?

Now it looks like:

```
Block 1 Block 2
```

I want:

```
Block 1
<!-- Margin here -->
Block 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try in this way:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 form-group">Block 1</div>
   <div class="col-md-12 form-group">Block 2</div> 
</div>
```